# Display result of query in columns instead of lines

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table looking like this :

```
Company | FCurrency | ... | FDate      | FAmount
aaa     | EUR       | ... | 01-01-2014 | 5
aaa     | EUR       | ... | 01-02-2014 | 8
aaa     | EUR       | ... | 01-03-2014 | 9
aaa     | EUR       | ... | 01-04-2014 | -2
aaa     | USD       | ... | 01-01-2014 | 1
aaa     | USD       | ... | 01-02-2014 | 2
aaa     | USD       | ... | 01-03-2014 | 3
aaa     | USD       | ... | 01-04-2014 | 4
```

And I would like to write a query which result would be something like :

```
Company | FCurrency | ... | 01-01-2014 | 01-02-2014 | 01-03-2014 | 01-04-2014 |
aaa     | EUR       | ... | 5          | 8          | 9          | -2         |
aaa     | USD       | ... | 1          | 2          | 3          | 4          |
```

I found a way to do it in VBA in excel but it takes a long time (because I have many many records) so I thought if access can do it for me it is much better.

In access i found this post : [Displaying multiple columns from a single column select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651097/displaying-multiple-columns-from-a-single-column-select-statement) but it does not do what I want as it still outputs only one record per line, instead of merging them into one line.

Also to merge the currency and company, I know how to do with GROUP BY, but my problem is to have the different 'new' columns, and I have to admit I am a bit lost there.

Thanks in advance.

V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a crosstab query.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx

The SQL for the example data/table you gave

```
TRANSFORM Sum(FAmount) AS SumOfFAmount
SELECT Company, FCurrency
FROM MyTableName
GROUP BY Company, FCurrency
PIVOT FDate;
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are a Genius !
It is exactly what I wanted!
Thank you so much !